# laravel 5.2 - Model::all() order by

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I get the full collection of a Model with the following:

`$posts = Post::all();`

However I want this is reverse chronological order.

What is the best way to get this collection in the desired order?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

You can use the orderBy method. Replace the column name with the one you want.

Answer (score 14):

You can now use `sortBy` or `sortByDesc`:

```
$posts = Post::all()->sortBy('created_at');
```

Comment: I'm forever forgetting this, why dont they just call it orderby?

Comment: @HarryBosh i guess it's because they want to differentiate between the Collection method (sortBy) and the Eloquent method (orderBy).

Comment: It's better to use `Post::orderBy` because this will do the ordering in the query, instead of afterwards on the result returned by the query. E.g. if you add pagination later, `Post::all()->sortBy` will break, because it will get e.g. the first 20 posts in random order from the database, and _then_ order them.

Answer (score 2):

As many may be moving to newer versions of Laravel, you can use ::latest() starting in 5.3 - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset .