# Laravel Eloquent Descending Order

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
public function blog()
{

    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('blog')->with(  [
      'posts' => $posts,

    ]);
```

this is my function in the controller

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35250080/laravel-5-2-modelall-order-by/35250160

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel 5.2 - Model::all() order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35250080/laravel-5-2-modelall-order-by)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it as below

First method :

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

Second Method :

```
$posts = Post::latest();
```

Comment: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()"

Comment: thank you so much instead of all I tried to get, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Please view this: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent. There are collections methods.

```
$urvar= Model::orderBy('column_name', 'DESC')->get();
```